# Having trouble implementing react-redux in Lerna

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, lerna

I am using lerna to split my react project into modules, each one using a reduxjs-toolkit slice, here is an example of how it is structured

```
- packages
  - users
  - lib
  - core
  - config
  - root
  - other 8 modules...
```

Error raises when i try to add a new module, i use a custom singleton class to merge all reducers

```js
import ReduxBuilder from "@core/redux/store"

// Middlewares
import cancelRequest from "@core/redux/middlewares/cancelRequest"
import { moduleChange } from "@core/redux/middlewares/moduleChange"

// Slices
import auth from "@mpbox/core/src/redux/slices/authentication"
import layout from "@mpbox/core/src/redux/slices/layout"
import navbar from "@core/redux/slices/navbar"
import profiles from "@mpbox/users/src/slices/profiles"
import profileDetail from "@mpbox/users/src/slices/profiles/detail"
import users from "@mpbox/users/src/slices/users"
import userDetail from "@mpbox/users/src/slices/users/detail"
import table from "@mpbox/lib/src/components/TableSection/slices"
import nipRequest from "@mpbox/portability/src/slices/nip-request/main"
import requestPort from "@mpbox/portability/src/slices/portability-request/main"
import requestPortDetail from "@mpbox/portability/src/slices/portability-request/detail"
import sales from "@mpbox/sales/src/slices/sales-report/main"
import salesDetail from "@mpbox/sales/src/slices/sales-report/detail"
import salesRegister from "@mpbox/sales/src/slices/sales-register/main"
import emailSettings from "@mpbox/config/src/slices/email-settings/main"
import bannerSettings from "@mpbox/config/src/slices/banner-settings/main"
import bannerSettingsDetail from "@mpbox/config/src/slices/banner-settings/detail"
import pointsReport from "@mpbox/points/src/slices/points/main"
import expressPortability from "@mpbox/portability/src/slices/express-portability/main"
import communicationsReport from "@mpbox/communications/src/slices/communications/main"
import comunicationSettings from "@mpbox/communications/src/slices/communication-settings/main"
import comunicationSettingsDetail from "@mpbox/communications/src/slices/communication-settings/detail"
import uploadFiles from "@mpbox/upload-files/src/slices/upload-files/main"

// Types
import { CurriedGetDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/getDefaultMiddleware"

const reducers = {
  auth,
  layout,
  navbar,
  table,
  profiles,
  profileDetail,
  users,
  userDetail,
  nipRequest,
  requestPort,
  requestPortDetail,
  sales,
  salesDetail,
  salesRegister,
  emailSettings,
  bannerSettings,
  bannerSettingsDetail,
  pointsReport,
  expressPortability,
  communicationsReport,
  comunicationSettings,
  comunicationSettingsDetail,
  uploadFiles
}

const builder = ReduxBuilder.getInstance(reducers)
const currentReducers = builder.getReducer()
builder.appendMiddlewares(
  (
    getDefaultMiddleware: CurriedGetDefaultMiddleware<typeof currentReducers>
  ) => {
    return getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }).concat(
      moduleChange.middleware,
      cancelRequest.middleware
    )
  }
)

export type AppDispatch = typeof builder.dispatch // eslint-disable-line
export const store = builder.getStore() // eslint-disable-line

builder.setDispatch(builder.getStore()?.dispatch)

export default builder
```

When i start the dev server, it shows the next error:
[image: react-redux error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a]

```js
const store = reduxBuilder.getStore()
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("app") as HTMLElement)

root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
        <ThemeContext>
          <Wrapper>
            <App />
          </Wrapper>
        </ThemeContext>
      </Suspense>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```

package versions:

```json
    "react-redux": "8.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.5",
    "redux": "4.2.0",
    "redux-debounced": "0.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.1",
    "react": "18.1.0"
```

The first modules works, but when i try to add a new one and register the slice, it shows that error, I made sure the Provider is wrapping my application, also try made certain modules have peerDependencies like react or react-redux, but it just doesn't work and throw the same error, how can i solve it?